# Cannot ping outside but can browse

Tags: browser, ping

I can `ping` `localhost` and `gateway`, but I cannot `ping` outside in command line, e.g. `google.com`.

I can use the browser to browse everything, this works fine.

I tried to `ssh` to another server, but it fails as well.

Anyone knows what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a firewall enabled for outgoing packets in your router or
Some times your Internet Service Provide  disables the icmp packages a.k.a ping packets also some disables some of common ports as ssh all this done with a firewall that your provider have been setup. You can call your provider to open all those ports.